# How to apply a bockwise transpose to a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I know this question is very basic but I am looking for the best way to do this. My question is How could we reshape a numpy array as the vertical arrow in the attached pictures? [image: numpy reshape]

In the end, I want to reshape a 120*64*200 to 1200*64*20!

Comment: My first instinct is to reshape it to (120, 64,10,20) (or 120,64,20,10)).  Then transpose/swap axes to make a (120, 10, 64, 20) and finally reshape to (1200, 65,20).  Reshape and swap alternatives will affect the final layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
n_blocks = 2
b = np.concatenate(np.split(a, n_blocks, axis=1), axis=0)
```

You basically want to split the array into blocks and concatenate the blocks on a new axis.

Comment: transpose is also possible

Answer (score 4):

you can do it also with [transpose](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html)

```
arr = np.array([i for i in range(1,19)])

arr3d = arr.reshape(3, 2,-1)    # (1)

print(arr3d)

arr3d = arr3d.transpose(1,0,2)  # (2) magic happens here

print(arr3d)

arr3d = arr3d.reshape(-1,3)     # (3)

print(arr3d)
```

after first reshape, the content will be:

```
[[[ 1  2  3]
  [ 4  5  6]]

 [[ 7  8  9]
  [10 11 12]]

 [[13 14 15]
  [16 17 18]]]
```

with magical transpose you will get:

```
[[[ 1  2  3]
  [ 7  8  9]
  [13 14 15]]

 [[ 4  5  6]
  [10 11 12]
  [16 17 18]]]
```

and then just reshape to 2d.

With method chaining, we can combine into one statement, like:

```
arr.reshape(3, 2, -1).transpose(1, 0, 2).reshape(-1, 3)
```